# How to deal with authority bias?

Tags: culture

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authority_bias

> Authority bias is the tendency to attribute greater accuracy to the
>   opinion of an authority figure (unrelated to its content) and be more
>   influenced by that opinion. The Milgram experiment in 1961 was the
>   classic experiment that established its existence.

I have experienced that some people that have a lot of influence promote silos and are anti DevOps. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're not the only one with such experiences :)

One possible approach today (which wasn't available in the early DevOps days) is to counter-argument with the many research-based publications from industry-recognized influencers. Like [Accelerate](https://itrevolution.com/book/accelerate/) or [2017 State of DevOps Report](https://puppet.com/resources/whitepaper/state-of-devops-report) to name a few.

Another approach could be to propose and implement DevOps-based pilot projects to actually measure and compare performance parameters against the existing silo'd solutions. This *could* be tricky, though, as those influencers could insist on requirements cornering the pilot projects. For example insisting on individual/small team development speed which could be an obstacle for optimizing and speeding up the overall larger/entire project team's development.

Comment: In my case CTO refused to read anything I was giving to read, also he asked others to ignore me too.

Comment: @Nakilon Personally I'd start looking for another job, but please don't take it as an advice - only you can evaluate if the job's benefits outweigh the cons in your case.